# Оптимизация SQL запроса. Можно ли заменить UNION?

Tags: sql, sql-server, оптимизация

Предположим, есть вот такой абстрактный запрос для отчета:

```
select 'Общие затраты', SUM(price1) as field11,SUM(price2) as field2 from Table1
UNION
select 'Затраты на сотрудников', SUM(price3) as field11,SUM(price4) as field2 from Table1
```

Т.е несколько раз идет обращение к одной и той же таблице, но считаются разные поля, а каждая составная часть `UNION`- это отдельная строчка отчета.

Можно ли как-нибудь уйти от `UNION` и сосчитать все за 1 одно обращение к таблице, но что бы результат был таким же как у UNION?

**UPD 1**

Протестировал вариант от @MaxU на боевом запросе.

Время выполнения ~1:04. Не сильно отличается от исходного варианта.

Из некоторых соображений, я сделал анонимизацию таблиц и колонок.

```
USE Database1

DECLARE Variable1 INT=?

;WITH Object1 as (
    SELECT CAST(Function1(DISTINCT Object2.Column1) AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Column2,
       CAST(
           Function1(DISTINCT
                CASE 
                             WHEN 
             Object3.Column3 not  in (?) THEN  Object2.Column1 ELSE ? END
           ) AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column4,
       CAST(
           Function1( DISTINCT
                CASE 
                    WHEN Object3.Column3 in (?)
                THEN  Object2.Column1 ELSE ? END
           )  AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column5,
       CAST(
           Function1(DISTINCT
                CASE 
                             WHEN Object3.Column3=?
               THEN  Object2.Column1 ELSE ? END
           ) AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column6,
       CAST(Function2(Object2.Column7) AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Column8,
       CAST(
           Function2(
                CASE 
                             WHEN 
             Object3.Column3 not  in (?) THEN  Object2.Column7 ELSE ? END
           ) AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column9,
       CAST(
           Function2( 
                CASE 
                             WHEN Object3.Column3 in (?)
                THEN  Object2.Column7 ELSE ? END
           )  AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column10,
       CAST(
           Function2(
                CASE 
                             WHEN Object3.Column3=?
               THEN  Object2.Column7 ELSE ? END
           ) AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column11 
    FROM   Object4 Object2 WITH(NOLOCK)
       JOIN Database2.Schema1.Object5 Object6 WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON  Object6.Column12 = Object2.Column12
            AND Object6.Column13 = Variable1 
       JOIN Database2.Schema1.Object7 Object3 WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON  Object3.Column3 = Object6.Column3
            AND Object3.Column13 = Variable1
        where Column14=? AND Object6.Column15!=?
)
SELECT ? AS Column16,Column2 AS Column17,Column4 AS Column18,Column11 AS Column19,Column5 AS Column20 FROM Object1 AS Object2
UNION ALL
SELECT ?,Column8,Column9,Column10,Column11  FROM Object1 AS Object2
```

Получил вот такой план:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень странно... На 3 верхних уровнях все загоняется во временную таблицу, но на самом нижнм уровне происходит повторное чтение исходной таблицы.

Если убрать UNION, то нижний уровень пропадает. Т.е UNION CTE приводит к повторному чтению.

Конечно, есть предположение, что второго чтения фактически не происходит и данные забираются из кеша, но все равно странно. Почему оптимизатор не решает забрать эти данные из темповой таблицы, а снова лезит и агрегирует все.

**UPD 2**

Протестировал вариант от @i-one.

Время выполнения: 1:37

Запрос выглядет так:

```
USE Database1

DECLARE Variable1 INT=?

;WITH Object1 as (
    SELECT CAST(Function1(DISTINCT Object2.Column1) AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Column2,
       CAST(
           Function1(DISTINCT
                CASE 
                             WHEN 
             Object3.Column3 not  in (?) THEN  Object2.Column1 ELSE ? END
           ) AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column4,
       CAST(
           Function1( DISTINCT
                CASE 
                    WHEN Object3.Column3 in (?)
                THEN  Object2.Column1 ELSE ? END
           )  AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column5,
       CAST(
           Function1(DISTINCT
                CASE 
                             WHEN Object3.Column3=?
               THEN  Object2.Column1 ELSE ? END
           ) AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column6,
       CAST(Function2(Object2.Column7) AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS Column8,
       CAST(
           Function2(
                CASE 
                             WHEN 
             Object3.Column3 not  in (?) THEN  Object2.Column7 ELSE ? END
           ) AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column9,
       CAST(
           Function2( 
                CASE 
                             WHEN Object3.Column3 in (?)
                THEN  Object2.Column7 ELSE ? END
           )  AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column10,
       CAST(
           Function2(
                CASE 
                             WHEN Object3.Column3=?
               THEN  Object2.Column7 ELSE ? END
           ) AS NVARCHAR(50)
       )  AS Column11 
    FROM   Object4 Object2 WITH(NOLOCK)
       JOIN Database2.Schema1.Object5 Object6 WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON  Object6.Column12 = Object2.Column12
            AND Object6.Column13 = Variable1 
       JOIN Database2.Schema1.Object7 Object3 WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON  Object3.Column3 = Object6.Column3
            AND Object3.Column13 = Variable1
        where Column14=? AND Object6.Column15!=?
)
SELECT Object8.Column16,Object8.Column17,Object8.Column18,Object8.Column19,Object8.Column20 FROM Object1 AS Object2
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (?,Column2,Column4,Column11,Column5),(?,Column8,Column9,Column11,Column5)) a(title,field1,field2,field3,field4)
```

План:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно по плану, пропало повторное чтение, но время выполнения стало выше варианта, который предложил @MaxU выше.

Comment: Судя по плану, львиная доля ресурсов уходит на поиск (Key Lookup) по индексу Object4.Index4, и по-моему (у меня почти нет опыта чтения планов SQL Server) оптимизатор решил читать/искать по этому индексу параллельно - от этого четвертая строка

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться конструкцией [WITH common_table_expression as (...) select ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
with tab
as
(
    select sum(price1) as p1, sum(price2) as p2,
           sum(price3) as p3, sum(price4) as p4 from Table1
)
select 'Общие затраты', p1 as field11, p2 as field2 from tab
union all
select 'Затраты на сотрудников', p3, p4 from tab;
```

> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table
>   expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and defined
>   within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statement. This clause can also be used in a CREATE VIEW
>   statement as part of its defining SELECT statement. A common table
>   expression can include references to itself. This is referred to as a
>   recursive common table expression.

PS если не нужно избавляться от дупликатов, то лучше воспользоваться `UNION ALL` - это менне затратная операция

Comment: А с точки зрения производительности, будет профит, чем использования обычного UNION, как в вопросе?

Comment: Надо смотреть план выполнения запроса. У меня нет возможности проверить на SQL Server... По идее, используя `WITH ...` оптимизатор не должен сканировать`Table1` более одного раза

Comment: ,Хм... Планы идентичные. Вероятнее всего, оптимизатор сам выносит повторяющиеся куски в CTE. Профит от CTE конечно есть, так как повышается удобночитаемость код в следствии отсутствия дублей.

Comment: @iluxa1810, я обновил ответ - попробуйте сравнить планы сейчас...

Comment: вот сейчас, действительно произошло упрощение на целый 1 уровень в плане.

Comment: @iluxa1810, скорее всего это результат замены `UNION` на `UNION ALL`

Comment: @MadU, проверил. Планы с ALL и без него одинаковые. Профит все таки в переносе вычислений в CTE.

Comment: хммм... в Oracle планы бы точно разные были ... Может оптимизатор увидел каким-то образом что дупликатов не может быть и сам преобразовал `UNION` --> `UNION ALL`...

Comment: @MadU,возможно, он увидел разные литералы и выполнил преобразование. Однако, то что пропал 1 уровень в плане запроса по факту не дало значительных выигрышей в производительности. Всего пара секунд.

Comment: @MadU, я немного обновил вопрос, по результатами тестирования вашего ответа. Так же добавил план.

Comment: @pluxa1810, да с планом запроса - интереснее...

Answer (score 2):

Да, по смыслу тут скорее `UNION ALL` а не `UNION`.

Можно так:

```
;with s as (
    select
        s1 = SUM(price1),
        s2 = SUM(price2),
        s3 = SUM(price3),
        s4 = SUM(price4)
    from Table1
)
select a.title, a.field11, a.field2
from s
    cross apply (values
        (N'Общие затраты', s.s1, s.s2),
        (N'Затраты на сотрудников', s.s3, s.s4)) a(title, field11, field2);
```

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавив результаты тестирования вашего ответа.

Comment: @iluxa1810, судя по планам вариант с `cross apply` делает меньше чтений (вообще можно включить `set statistics io, time on` и сравнить вывод для двух запросов), но вариант с `union all` видимо лучше параллелизуется (скорее всего две части `union all` выбираются независимо и параллельно). Нижняя ветка в плане - это по-видимому вторая часть `union all` (где только `sum()`), верхняя ветка с TableSpool - это первая часть (где `sum()` и `count(distinct)`).

Comment: @iluxa1810, от Key Lookup можно избавиться, если занести нужные столбцы в индекс (в `include` или как часть ключа, если это нужно). Ну и `count(distinct)` конечно всё очень осложняет. Если бы там были просто `count`, то всё было бы значительно проще (никакого Table Spool скорее всего не было бы).

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
select metname, 
SUM(case when met=1 then price1 else price3 end) as field11,
SUM(case when met=1 then price2 else price4 end ) as field2 
from Table1
left join  (select 1 met, 'Общие затраты' metname 
      union select 2, 'Затраты на сотрудников') t
/* where ... */ group by metname
```

Условия case when нужно что б подставить условия на подсчёт метода 1 и метода 2 одновременно, будте так же внимательны, условие where должно стабатывать и для met=1 и для met=2, остальные условия надо в case.